# How would I add reaction roles to my strangely coded bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This bot is a very simple bot that is private and won't be publicized. It does not use / commands for reasons I won't say here, so it uses the prefix !!. When someone replies to a message the bot made with a command, it will comply with that command. The arguments of the command are separated by commas.

Example:
[image: An example of a user replying to Bot Yozy (the bot I am talking about) with a command that reads: !!remind/false/600/Time's up! {role}/1046581095346491523/1046563446591852624/]

There is also a / at the end to tell the bot that the command has ended.

So what I actually want to add to the bot is a command that sets reaction roles with 5 arguments. The first argument would be the reaction role type. Users would put Give or Remove. Normal would give the user a role and Remove would take a role away. Timed  roles would also be in the bot but they are set up differently; they would give the user a role for a certain amount of time before removing it. For all of them, the bot would automatically remove the user's reaction once they add it so that they wouldn't need to click the reaction twice to re-add the role.

The second argument would be for timed roles. Users would put something that isn't a number if they don't want the role to be timed and would put a number if they want the role to be timed. The number would be how many seconds the role is given/taken before the role change being reverted. So if the first argument was Give and the second argument was 4 then clicking the reaction would give the user a role for 4 seconds before removing it again. The third and fourth arguments are for the message ID to put the reaction role and the actual reaction's ID respectively. These are self explanatory. Lastly, the fifth argument is the emoji that the reaction role would use.

Obviously I know how to script most of this. What I'm having trouble with is figuring out the basics of reactions, like how to detect when a reaction is added to a certain message. I would've asked for only that but I figured my question would be better answered if I gave as much context on this bot as possible. I've searched up this problem and looked everywhere but haven't gotten anything due to how weirdly coded my bot is. As you can probably tell, it's mostly a side project so I don't wish to learn how to make a proper advanced bot, at least not now.

Anyways, here is the full code for the bot (the beginning of the reaction roles command is near the bottom):

```
import os
import discord
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import logging
import time
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

# When IP abuse occurs, type "kill 1" in the Shell tab.

logging.basicConfig(
  format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s",
  level=logging.INFO,
)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("I'm in")

global remindcmd
remindcmd = "neither" #values = true, false, neither

global remindDebounce
remindDebounce = "free" #values = free, notfree

def convert_timezone(from_tz, to_tz, datetime):
    # Set the timezone for the input datetime
    from_tz = pytz.timezone(from_tz)
    datetime = from_tz.localize(datetime)

    # Convert the datetime to the desired timezone
    to_tz = pytz.timezone(to_tz)
    return datetime.astimezone(to_tz)

# Entries 
from_tz = 'America/Los_Angeles'
to_tz = 'utc'
datetime_input = datetime(2022, 12, 19, 6, 55, 00)
converted_datetime = convert_timezone(from_tz, to_tz, datetime_input)

@client.event
async def help(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="!! HELP WITH BOT YOZY COMMANDS !!", url='https://docs.google.com/document/d/1092IyGbNHhahD7z7Q_cXxPwa5kXwgjUHqHxYS97IShY/', description='A command will only be detected by Bot Yozy if the message using it is replying to a prior message from the bot, or if the bot is pinged in the message (though this is not advised because of the following).\n**Commands must start with the prefix "!!" and end with "/" (with the exception of !!help and !!listen) to be detected.** Each argument should also be separated with a "/" when giving the bot a command with multiple arguments.\n⠀', color=0x808080)
    embed.add_field(name="!!help", value="The command that opens this very help screen. Make sure to ping the bot in the same message!\n⠀", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="!!listen", value="Simply triggers the bot to send a message, allowing you to reply to the message to use other commands with ease. Make sure to ping the bot in the same message!\n⠀", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="!!reverse", value="Reverses a message. Argument 1 is the message you want to reverse. Simple!\nExample: !!reverse/This message is reversed!/\n⠀", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="!!remind", value='Lets the bot remind a role (through pinging) after a certain amount of time has passed!\nArgument 1 is the amount of time in seconds the bot should wait before pinging the role.\nArgument 2 is whether you want the bot to loop this command, meaning it will wait the amount of time specified in Argument 1, ping the role, then wait the amount of time again, then ping the role again, and repeat the process until it is turned off. This argument should either be "true" or "false".\nArgument 3 is the message the bot says when pinging the role. Make sure to use the term "{role}" in the message with the curly brackets and without the quotes, because that is where the ping will be. This can only be done once!\nArgument 4 is the ID of the channel that the role ping will appear in.\nArgument 5 is the ID of the role that the bot will ping.\nExample: !!remind/2/true/I just pinged (role)!/1234567890/0987654321/\n⠀', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="!!timesince", value='States the time since a set date. There are 3 arguments that define the date you want the bot to calculate the time since. Put "botrelease" instead of 3 arguments to get the age of the bot!\nArgument 1 is the month.\nArgument 2 is the day.\nArgument 3 is the year.\nExample: !!timesince/4/23/2022/\n⠀', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="!!selfdestruct", value='Initiates the self destruct sequence.\n!! DO NOT USE !!', inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  global remindDebounce
  global remindcmd

  if message.author.bot:
    return

  if message.content.__contains__("!!help"):
    print("!!help command detected")
    await help(message.channel)
  
  if message.content.__contains__("!!listen"):
    print("!!listen command detected.")
    await message.channel.send("Listening for command input. Please reply to this message with your command.")

  if message.content.__contains__("!!test"):
    print("Test")

  if message.content.startswith("!!"):
    if message.content.endswith("/"):
      if message.content.startswith("!!reverse/"):
          revmsg = message.content[message.content.find("/")+1:-1]
          await message.channel.send(revmsg[::-1])
  
      if message.content.startswith("!!saysecretcmd/"):
        print(message.content[15:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)])
        message_channel = client.get_channel(int(message.content[15:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)]))
        print(f"Got channel {message_channel} !!saysecretcmd")
        saymsg = message.content[message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1:-1]
        print(f"Said the message, {saymsg}")
        await message_channel.send(saymsg)
      
      if message.content.startswith("!!remind/"):
        if remindDebounce == "free":
          if not message.content.startswith("!!remind/stop/"):
            print("Debounce was free")
            remindDebounce = "notfree"
        
            arg1 = message.content[9:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)]
            arg2 = message.content[message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)]
            arg3 = message.content[message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)+1:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)+1)]
            arg4 = message.content[message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)+1)+1:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)+1)+1)]
            arg5 = message.content[message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)+1)+1)+1:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)]
            print(arg1)
            print(arg2)
            print(arg3)
            print(arg4)
            print(arg5)
      
            if arg2 == "false":
              print("Unlooped")
              await message.channel.send(f"Set up timer for {arg1} seconds.")
              time.sleep(float(arg1))
              message_channel_un = client.get_channel(int(arg4))
              role_un = message_channel_un.guild.get_role(int(arg5))
              await message_channel_un.send(arg3.replace("{role}", role_un.mention))
              remindDebounce = "free"
        
            else:
              print("Looped")
              print(arg1)
              print(arg2)
              print(arg3)
              print(arg4)
              print(arg5)
              print("arg variables printed")

              @tasks.loop(seconds=float(arg1))
              async def ping_start(message, target_channel_id, role_id):
                print("Entered async ping start")
                global remindcmd
                global remindDebounce
                print(remindcmd)
                message_channel = client.get_channel(int(target_channel_id))
                role = message_channel.guild.get_role(int(role_id))
                if remindcmd == "false":
                  remindcmd = "neither"
                  remindDebounce = "free"
                  print("Stopped")
                  ping_start.cancel()
                  await message_channel.send("Command successfully reset.")
                  print("remindcmd variable set to neither")
                print(f"Got channel {message_channel} !!remind")
                await message_channel.send(message.replace("{role}", role.mention))
                remindcmd = "true"
                print(remindcmd)
              
                @ping_start.before_loop
                async def before():
                  await client.wait_until_ready()
                  print("Finished waiting")
              
              ping_start.start(arg3, arg4, arg5)
              
        else:
          if not message.content.startswith("!!remind/stop/"):
            print("Debounce was not free")
            await message.channel.send("!!remind is currently running. Please stop the current command before trying again or wait for it to reset if it was already stopped.")
            
      if message.content.startswith("!!remind/stop/"):
        print("Stop command detected")
        await message.channel.send("Loop stopped. Please wait for the !!remind command to reset before using again. If this takes too long, tell the owner to reset it.")
        print(remindcmd)
        remindcmd = "false"
        print(remindcmd)
        print("remindcmd variable set to false")

      if message.content.startswith("!!timesince/"):
          arg1time = message.content[12:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)] # month
          arg2time = message.content[message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)] # day
          arg3time = message.content[message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)+1:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)+1)] # year
          if message.content.startswith("!!timesince/botrelease/"):
            arg1time = "12"
            arg2time = "22"
            arg3time = "2022"
          arguments = f"{arg1time}/{arg2time}/{arg3time} 0 hours, 0 minutes, & 0 seconds"

          msg_time = datetime.strptime(arguments, "%m/%d/%Y %H hours, %M minutes, & %S seconds")
          now_time = datetime.now()
          diff = now_time - msg_time
          print('msg_time:', msg_time)
          print('now_time:', now_time)
          print('diff:', diff)
          
          diff0 = str(diff)[0:str(diff).find(",")]
          diff1 = str(diff)[str(diff).find(",")+2:str(diff).find(":")]
          diff2 = str(diff)[str(diff).find(":")+1:str(diff).find(":", str(diff).find(":")+1)]
          diff3 = str(diff)[str(diff).find(":", str(diff).find(":")+1)+1:len(str(diff))+1]

          if int(diff1) == 1:
            diff1 = diff1 + " hour"
          else:
            diff1 = diff1 + " hours"

          if int(diff2) == 1:
            diff2 = diff2 + " minute"
          else:
            diff2 = diff2 + " minutes"

          diff3 = float(diff3)
          diff3 = round(diff3)
          diff3 = str(diff3)
          
          if int(diff3) == 1:
            diff3 = diff3 + " second"
          else:
            diff3 = diff3 + " seconds"
          
          print('diff0:', diff0)
          print('diff1:', diff1)
          print('diff2:', diff2)
          print('diff3:', diff3)
          
          await message.channel.send(f"It has been {diff0}, {diff1}, {diff2}, and {diff3} since this date.")

      if message.content.startswith("!!selfdestruct/"):
        print("Self destruct command detected")
        await message.channel.send("!! SELF DESTRUCT SEQUENCE INITIATED !!")
        time.sleep(3)
        await message.channel.send("!! TEN !!")
        time.sleep(1)
        await message.channel.send("!! NINE !!")
        time.sleep(1)
        await message.channel.send("!! EIGHT !!")
        time.sleep(1)
        await message.channel.send("!! SEVEN !!")
        time.sleep(1)
        await message.channel.send("!! SIX !!")
        time.sleep(1)
        await message.channel.send("!! FIVE !!")
        time.sleep(1)
        await message.channel.send("!! FOUR !!")
        time.sleep(1)
        await message.channel.send("!! THREE !!")
        time.sleep(1)
        await message.channel.send("!! TWO !!")
        time.sleep(1)
        await message.channel.send("!! ONE !!")
        time.sleep(1)
        await message.channel.send("Keyword detected! Revival protocol initiated...")
        time.sleep(3)
        await message.channel.send("one")

      if message.content.startswith("!!timezoneinfo/"):
        print("Timezone info command detected")
        print(pytz.all_timezones)
        message.channel.send("The list of timezones used for time-related commands can be found here:\nhttps://docs.google.com/document/d/11oBD10WfO8nuPiJSy_ozZmhj8lx2dWhuJIiBi2z-lbQ/edit")

      if message.content.startswith("!!deathsecretcmd/"):
        message_channel_death = client.get_channel(int(message.content[17:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)]))
        print(f"Got channel {message_channel_death} !!death")
        await message_channel_death.send("Keyword detected! Revival protocol initiated...")
        time.sleep(3)
        await message_channel_death.send("one")

      if message.content.startswith("!!startsecretcmd/"):
        message_channel = client.get_channel(int(message.content[17:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)]))
        print(f"Got channel {message_channel} !!startsecretcmd")
        addmsg = message.content[message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1:-1]
        
        if addmsg == "0":
          await message_channel.send('Hello, I am Bot Yozy! A high quality bot for all your bot needs! Need help on how to use me? Ping me in a message containing "!!help" to refer to my help page.')
          print("Said the !!start message without an additional message!")
        else:
          if addmsg.startswith("detach."):
            sleeptimedetached = message[message.find("detach.") + 7]
            print(f"sleeptimedetached: {sleeptimedetached}")
            await message_channel.send('Hello, I am Bot Yozy! A high quality bot for all your bot needs! Need help on how to use me? Ping me in a message containing "!!help" to refer to my help page.')
            time.sleep(1)
            await message_channel.send(addmsg)
            print(f"Said the !!start message with the detached additional message: {addmsg}")
          else:
            await message_channel.send('Hello, I am Bot Yozy! A high quality bot for all your bot needs! Need help on how to use me? Ping me in a message containing "!!help" to refer to my help page.')
            print(f"Said the !!start message with the additional message: {addmsg}")
            
      if message.content.startswith("!!additem/"):
        item = message.content[10:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)]
        channelid = 1068222716043329697
        messageid = 1068223388583207084
        fetchedchannel = await client.fetch_channel(channelid)
        fetchedmessage = await fetchedchannel.fetch_message(messageid)
        itemdesc = "undefined"
        if item == "flashlight":
          itemdesc = "Flashlight  - Given to players at the beginning of the game. Because it is low on batteries, it will only last until the 5-minute mark. If it runs out of battery, the player's chances of survival will decrease drastically."
        if item == "battery":
          itemdesc = "Battery  - Once obtained, it will make a flashlight last for the rest of the game. There are 5 of these, one for each flashlight, and it is important that they are found during the first 5 minutes of the game."
        if item == "key":
          itemdesc = "Key ️ - Opens any general room of the player's choice, but can only be used once."
        if item == "generator key":
          itemdesc = "Generator Key  - Turns on the Generator."
        if item == "question key":
          itemdesc = "Question Key ❔ - Unlocks the Community Questions."
        if item == "hint":
          itemdesc = "Hint  - Players may DM Yozy McLean with a question to use up a hint. The question will be answered or hinted at the answer based on how direct it is."
        if item == "trap":
          itemdesc = "Trap  - Will save the player holding it from dying."
        if item == "box":
          itemdesc = "Box  - An item that players can stack to reach high places."
        if item == "potato":
          itemdesc = "Potato  - potato"
        if item == "uranium":
          itemdesc = "Uranium - An item that can be used by any player, or more frequently by cookiechocy, in order to subside their hunger. Taken directly from Insanity's uranium stash."
        if item == "titanium":
          itemdesc = "Titanium - An item that can be used by any player, or more frequently by cookiechocy, in order to subside their hunger."
        if item == "secret item":
          itemdesc = "Secret Item  - Allows players to instantly escape the facility! (not really)"
        if item == "bread":
          itemdesc = "Bread  - A deluxe and gourmet dish that can cure any craving for all foods amazing."
        if item == "duck":
          itemdesc = "Duck  - Eater of bread."
        if item == "revive":
          itemdesc = "Revive ❤️ - Revives a dead teammate!"
        if item == "wall":
          itemdesc = "Wall  - I WILL BUILD A GREAT WALL, BUILD A GREAT WALL"
        if item == "reset":
          await fetchedchannel.send("Are you sure you want to reset? Use the command with 'resetitemguide.0' to confirm reset.")
          return
        if item == "resetitemguide.0":
          await fetchedmessage.edit(content="**Item Guide:**\n\n*Reply to this message with the !!additem command to add an item to the guide!*")
          await fetchedchannel.send("Successfully reset Item Guide.")
          return
        if item == "ur mom":
          await fetchedchannel.send("Denied ur mom because she does not exist lmao")
          return
        if itemdesc == "undefined":
          await fetchedchannel.send("Denied item: *" + item + "* because item does not exist.")
          return
        if fetchedmessage.content.__contains__(itemdesc):
          await fetchedchannel.send("Denied item: *" + item.capitalize() + "* because item already added.")
          return
        await fetchedmessage.edit(content=fetchedmessage.content + "\n\n"+ itemdesc)
        await fetchedchannel.send("Discovered item: *" + item.capitalize() + "*")
        print("Added item: " + item)

      if message.content.startswith("!!editsecretcmd/"):
        channelid = message.content[16:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)]
        messageid = message.content[message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)]
        newmessage = message.content[message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)+1:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)+1)]
        fetchchannel = await client.fetch_channel(channelid)
        fetchmessage = await fetchchannel.fetch_message(messageid)
        await fetchmessage.edit(content=newmessage)

      if message.content.startswith("!!addtosecretcmd/"):
        channelid = message.content[16:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)]
        messageid = message.content[message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)]
        newmessage = message.content[message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)+1:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)+1)]
        fetchchannel = await client.fetch_channel(channelid)
        fetchmessage = await fetchchannel.fetch_message(messageid)
        await fetchmessage.edit(content=message.content + newmessage)

      if message.content.startswith("!!remember/"):
        fetchchannel = await client.fetch_channel(1065059043997130813)
        fetchmessage = await fetchchannel.fetch_message(1065061418497482905)
        print("remember cmd")
        remembertype = message.content[11:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)]
        if remembertype == "speak":
          print("remember speak")
        else:
          if remembertype == "save":
            print("remember save")
            remembermessage = message.content[message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1:message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/", message.content.find("/")+1)+1)]
            
          else:
            print("argument 1 was not save or speak")

        if message.content.startswith("!!timedrole/"):
          #reaction roles here

    else: ###########
      if not message.content.__contains__("!!help"):
        if not message.content.__contains__("!!listen"):
          if not message.content.__contains__("!!test"):
            await message.channel.send("Commands must start with the prefix !! and end with / (with the exception of !!help and !!listen) to be detected. Please use the !!help page for more command info.")
        
# await message.channel.send("Message here")

keep_alive()
client.run(os.environ['Bot_Token_NOTCLIENTSECRET'])
```

Please help if you can, and sorry for making this post really long.

Comment: A statement needs to be added where `#reaction roles here` currently is, otherwise the `if` block would be considered incomplete.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Now I just need the actual reaction roles command (I'll continue looking on the internet while waiting for answers here)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of detecting a reaction being added:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(data):
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == data.guild_id, client.guilds)
    
    if data.emoji.name = "" and data.message_id == 12345678:
        Role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="English")
        Member = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id == data.user_id, guild.members)
        await Member.add_roles(Role)
```

Here, we detect when a reaction is added and can get data about it. From that we are checking which message we reacted to to make sure its the correct one and we check the actual reaction to make sure we got the expected one.  After that, we just take the role object and member object and add the role to the member object.

Comment: Is "data" a built-in discord parameter? If I want to call the function (to add it to the commands) what would I put in the parameters?

Comment: You can use any name that you like for the "data", some prefer to use "payload" etc. It just is the set of data returned on every reaction add. How would you implement this into a command anyway? I'm not sure I understand what exactly you want to do.

Comment: If you scroll all the way down in yhe code in the original post, you'll find a line that says "#reaction roles here". That's where the code that runs on command would be, and it's where I would want to add the reaction roles. Is there a way for me to incorporate the reaction roles code into the command?